# Failure of dominated convergence theorem but the result still holds(?).

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For $x>1$ let $g (x)=(x \log x)^{-1}$ & for $\{A_n\}$ a sequence of measurable subsets of  $[2,\infty)$ & $\{c_n\}$ a sequence of nonnegative numbers, we put $f_n=c_n \chi _{A_n}$.

if $\{f_n\}$ converges to $ 0 $  & for  every  $n $ ,$|f_n|\le g$,

prove or disprove  that  $\int _2 ^ {\infty}f_n dx$   converges to $ 0 $.

Here the  integral of $g $ is not finite ,so we can't use the dominated convergence theorem.but the result seems to hold.

Can anyone help me with  this problem? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct for the simple reason that $A_n\subseteq [2,t)$ where $t\log t=1/c_n$, so $\int f_n \le c_n t$ and $t\lesssim 1/(-c_n\log c_n)$.